# Kafka 1.0 Streaming API: message consumption from partitions get delayed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Recently, I've switched our streaming app from spark-streaming 2.1 to use kafka-streaming new API (1.0) with kafka broker server 0.11.0.0

I have implemented my own Processor class, and in process method, I just printed the message content.

I have a kafka cluster of 3 machines, and the topic I am hooking on have 300 partitions.

I ran the streaming app with 100 thread, on a machine with 32 GB of RAM, and 8 cores.

My problem is, in some cases, I got the messages once it reached the kafka topic/partition, and in other cases, I got the message after it has reached the topic with 10-15 minutes, Don't know why!

I used the below command line to track the lag on the kafka topic for the group.id for the streaming app.

`./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092 --new-consumer --describe  --group kf_streaming_gp_id`

but unfortunately it is not consistently give accurate results, or even give result at all, any body know why?

Is there is something I missed with the streaming app so that I can read the messages once reached the partitions consistently?
Any consumer properties fix such problem.

My kafka-streaming app structure is as below:

```
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kf_streaming_gp_id");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "kf_streaming_gp_id");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, DocumentSerde.class);
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomTimeExtractor.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 100);

        KStream<String, Document> topicStreams = builder.stream(sourceTopic);

        topicStreams.process(() -> new DocumentProcessor(appName, environment, dimensions, vector, sinkTopic));

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config);
        streams.start();
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of the kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand?

Comment: Running with 100 threads on a 8 core machine seems to be overkill... I would reduce the number of threads to 8. What is your overall data rate you write into the topic?

Comment: @kellanburket, the output sometimes says the group doesn't exist, I know an explanation for this but not sure if correct, which is at this exact moment the consumer was unhooked and trying to hook again. on the other times gives the normal lag output.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, having 8 threads on 3 partitions, will make each thread will have ~(300/8) partitions, which will lead to sort of lock if a thread is doing a CPU intensive process, I know the optimal concurrency is to have the number of thread = CPUs, I write about 4K message in a minute, and the system should handle those in Realtime

Comment: If the threads don't get CPU time, having some threads does not help. To address your concern that one thread cannot process the data for many partitions, you need to scale out your application! This will reduce the lag automatically. Ie, you need more processing power (hardware) to reduce the delay/lag.

Comment: @KarimTawfik I'm running a Kafka Application with 4 Streams apps, each using a 1 core apiece and no more than 5 threads per app and consume about 13k messages per minute with no lag and never get close to using up all of my cpu. I would look into the way you're loading data into Kafka. If partitioning isn't semantically important--which is probably isn't if you're processing your messages in streams--choose a round robin strategy so that all of your partitions are receiving the same number of messages, then repartition, if necessary in your app.

Comment: @KarimTawfik: Given that your input volume is low (<100 msg/s), have you tested your setup by running a single application instance with 1 core/thread to process all the data, and compare the results?  Or is the per-message processing so intensive (e.g. processing even 1 message takes a lot of CPU power) that you need this beefy hardware setup?

Comment: @kellanburket, partitioning is semantically important for my case, as I need to handle order of messages per partition, from my producer side, I am using linger.ms=3, and batch.size=50, to utilize the network communication between the producer and the broker.

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll, yes it is cpu intensive (doing lots of text processing and vectorization).  I will try your suggestion to make a vanilla consumer just reads the messages to make sure it is not kafka (consumer, producer, or broker problem)

Comment: @KarimTawfik yes, but is partitioning important before it hits the Streams API and if so, why? You can always repartition in Streams.

Comment: Guys, I turned out that there were threads stuck with doing a high CPU intensive work, which resulted in stopping other threads from consuming messages, that's why I saw such bursts, when I stopped this cpu intensive logic, everything was super fast, and messages gets to the streaming job once they got to the kafka topic.

Comment: In this case please create a new answer to this question with this info (threads were stuck with high CPU work) and mark it as accepted.  This will help other readers of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem in my case.

It turned out that there were threads stuck with doing a high CPU intensive work, which resulted in stopping other threads from consuming messages, that's why I saw such bursts, when I stopped this cpu intensive logic, everything was super fast, and messages gets to the streaming job once they got to the kafka topic.